# Break a function and see an error message

Tags: node.js, express

In the router, I usually use `req.json(object)` to return a correct result. Now, in some cases, i need to return an error message, for example

```
router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.username === null || req.body.username === undefined) {
        console.log("all fields please");
        // return res.status(400).json({ message: 'all fields please'});
        // res.send('all fields please')
    }

    console.log("not finished")
}
```

I tried `return res.status...` and `res.send...`, they either not finished or broke the function, or cannot show the message to the console.

Does anyone know which is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You tried both `return res.status` and `res.send` together??

Comment: No, either one or the other...

Comment: return will obviously break the function.....what msg you predicted on console `"not finished"` ??

Comment: i expected to see "all fields please"

Comment: that means `req.username` is neither undefined or null......nothing to do with send and return. Shouldnt it be `req.body.username`??

Comment: sorry, i wanted to write `req.body.username`... just corrected the OP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return res.status(400).json({ message: 'all fields please' })` does work. The thing is not to forget to catch in the front-end:

```
return $http.post('/register', user).then(function (res) {
        console.log("then: " + JSON.stringify(res.data))
    }).catch(function (res) {
        console.log("catch: " + JSON.stringify(res.data.message))
    })
}
```